# com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet cannot be cast to java.io.Closeable

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a problem when I try to close my connections ( my program works, but I get error at the end)

This is the chunk where the problem is ( it's related to the way I cast the connections into Closeable)

```
 private void close() {
    close((Closeable) resultSet);
    close((Closeable) statement);
    close((Closeable) connect);
  }
  private void close(Closeable c) {
    try {
      if (c != null) {
        c.close();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // don't throw now as it might leave following closables in undefined state
    }
```

This are the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet cannot be cast to java.io.Closeable
    at de.vogella.mysql.first.DeVogellaMysqlFirst.close(DeVogellaMysqlFirst.java:105)
    at de.vogella.mysql.first.DeVogellaMysqlFirst.readDataBase(DeVogellaMysqlFirst.java:68)
    at de.vogella.mysql.first.test.main(test.java:8)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

If I delete the cast method I get a syntax error.
Any suggestions ?
IMPORT

```
import java.lang.AutoCloseable;
```

CORRECTED VERSION :

```
private void close(AutoCloseable c) throws UnsupportedOperationException {
    try {
      if (c != null) {
        c.close();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    // don't throw now as it might leave following closables in undefined state
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet` cannot be cast to `java.io.Closeable` since it does not, nor any of its sub classes, implements the `Closable` interface.

If you change the close method to accept `java.lang.AutoCloseable` and cast to that type and not `java.io.Closable` it would probably work.

Comment: Should there be an `e` in `Closeable`?

Comment: You could also try `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.Closeable`.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution although it works is not optimal, instead I'd suggest to use try-with-resources. This ensures that all `AutoCloseable` (and `Closeable`) objects are closed in the correct order, even when exceptions occur. The added benefit is that you don't actually swallow/ignore exceptions.

For example:

```
try (
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(....)
) {
    // Process result set
}
// con, stmt and rs are guaranteed to have been closed here
```

See the tutorial [The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for details.